# Call a modal from a modal : close the first one

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a login modal on my website, where there is a form followed by a link like this :

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#register-modal">Not yet a member ?</a>
```

So, `register-modal` and `login-modal` are two different modals. Each of them has an ebedded close button :

```
<button type="button" id = "close" class="close" aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
```

As you can see, the purpose, when the user opens the login modal, is to allow him to click on register then open the `register-modal`.

But if he does so, I'd like the first modal to be automatically closed. Is there is a way to do se without writing JS/jQ or do I have to handle the event with jQ (for instance, if the user clicks on "not yet a member?", close the login-modal, open the register-modal).

Thanks

Comment: You have to write your own close handler; or just create one popup that has both forms.

Comment: there is no way to do without JS/jQ but you can do it with bootstrap modal events http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested, I didn't have to write any jQ nor handle any event. The solution is even more simple !

The only thing I had to do was to add `data-dismiss="modal"` to my link. As if I was dealing with a close button.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#register-modal" data-dismiss="modal">Not yet a member ?</a>
```

Clicking on "Not yet a member ?" closes the current modal (login) and opens the register modal. Thanks anyway for your help